# Facebook Marketing APi, get campaigns active LAST MONTH

Tags: node.js, api, facebook, facebook-graph-api, axios

I am currently really struggling with the Facebook Marketing API, specifically querying through our Ad Campaigns.

What we want, is for our query to return the ID's of the campaigns that were active during the previous month. However, when providing the 'effective_status' parameter, it only considers the status of the campaign AS IT IS NOW.

I am using this documentation here to navigate the API:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/campaigns/

Anyone have any ideas on how to structure the HTTP request? I have seen a few other similar questions on here with no avail.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Using this http request helped solve my issue :)

```
/act_{account_id}/insights?date_preset=this_month&level=campaign&fields=campaign_name
```